# Extracting time from text file

Tags: linux, text-processing, ping

So I am trying to write shell script in linux that will extract the rountrip time from a webserver ping stored in a text file. So what I basically have is a text file with this:

```
    PING e11699.b.akamaiedge.net (104.100.153.112) 56(84) bytes of data.
    64 bytes from a104-100-153-112.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (104.100.153.112): icmp_seq=1 ttl=60 time=17.2ms
    64 bytes from a104-100-153-112.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (104.100.153.112): icmp_seq=2 ttl=60 time=12.6ms
    64 bytes from a104-100-153-112.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (104.100.153.112): icmp_seq=3 ttl=60 time=11.7ms
    ... (a bunch more ping responses here)
    --- e11699.b.akamaiedge.net ping statistics ---
    86400 packets transmitted, 86377 received, 0% packet loss, time 86532481ms
    rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 6.281/18.045/1854.971/28.152 ms, pipe 2
```

So I ended up using sed to try and extract only the 17.2, 12.6, 11.7, and more times from the text file. below is my sed line:

```
    sed 's/.*(time=\([0-9]*\(\.[0-9]*\)\{0,1\}\) ms/\1/' pingoutput.txt | sort -n > sortedtime.txt
```

This line successfully extracted and sorted all the times I needed BUT it also extracted the few lines from the ping text file i didnt need. The text file it had created looked like this:

```
--- e11699.b.akamaiedge.net ping statistics ---
86400 packets transmitted, 86377 received, 0% packet loss, time 86532481ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 6.281/18.045/1854.971/28.152 ms, pipe 2
11.7
12.6
17.2
...
86400 packets transmitted, 86377 received, 0% packet loss, time 86532481ms
```

If there is anyway to avoid extracted the unwanted "---e11699" to "pipe 2" and the "86400 packets" to "86532481ms" lines of the text file I would really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this sed:

```
sed -n 's/.*time=\([0-9].*\)ms.*/\1/p' times | sort -n
```

On your example file (`times`):

```
PING e11699.b.akamaiedge.net (104.100.153.112) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from a104-100-153-112.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (104.100.153.112): icmp_seq=1 ttl=60 time=17.2ms
64 bytes from a104-100-153-112.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (104.100.153.112): icmp_seq=2 ttl=60 time=12.6ms
64 bytes from a104-100-153-112.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (104.100.153.112): icmp_seq=3 ttl=60 time=11.7ms
... (a bunch more ping responses here)
--- e11699.b.akamaiedge.net ping statistics ---
86400 packets transmitted, 86377 received, 0% packet loss, time 86532481ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 6.281/18.045/1854.971/28.152 ms, pipe 2
```

I get this result:

```
sed -n 's/.*time=\([0-9].*\)ms.*/\1/p' times | sort -n
11.7
12.6
17.2
```

I used the `-n` switch to get rid of unwanted lines.
From `man sed`:

`-n      By default, each line of input is echoed to the standard output after all of the commands have been applied to it.  The -n option suppresses this behavior.`

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you very much!

Comment: @user192314 My pleasure. Glad you were able to use it!

Comment: Would you be able to write the equivalent statement in python code instead of shell script?

Comment: @user192314 Yes, I could.

Comment: can you add it in as another answer

Comment: @user192314 Why don't you try it out yourself first. If it doesn't work for you, ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

if `grep` with `pcre` regex is okay:

```
$ grep -oP 'time=\K[0-9.]+' ip.txt | sort -n
11.7
12.6
17.2
```

- `-o` print only matching pattern
- `-P` use pcre regex
- `time=\K` positive lookbehind, not part of output
- `[0-9.]+` one or more of digits and `.` characters
- `sort -n` sort numerically

with `perl` alone:

```
$ perl -nle 'push(@a,/time=\K([0-9.]+)/g); END{ print foreach sort {$a <=> $b} @a }' ip.txt 
11.7
12.6
17.2
```

- here an array is populated with matching patterns and then at end, numerically sorted array is printed out

Answer (score -1):

```
grep 'time=' pingoutput.txt | awk '{print $8}'
```